# How can i obtain the feature names with thier scores from the results of mRMR.ensemble

Tags: feature-selection

I have question about `mRMR code`
I want to know that how I can obtain the feature names with their scores from `mRMR.ensemble`

```
data <- mRMR.data(data = data.frame(target=cgps.ic50, cgps.ge))

a<-mRMR.ensemble(data = data, target_indices = 1, feature_count = 30, solution_count = 1).

a$score

[1,] 0.008384749 [2,] 0.008334019 [3,] 0.009717827 [4,] 0.008925736 [5,] 
0.009806558 [6,] 0.009333292 [7,] 0.009982384 [8,] 0.009112271 [9,] 
0.009352187 [10,] 0.009355888 [11,] 0.009309922 [12,] 0.009443812 [13,] 
0.009309006 [14,] 0.009481970 [15,] 0.010900799 [16,] 0.010699199 [17,] 
0.011475124 [18,] 0.012622986 [19,] 0.011069654 [20,] 0.013246642 [21,] 
0.012665039 [22,] 0.013600446 [23,] 0.016588659 [24,] 0.021424912 [25,] 
0.017420170 [26,] 0.016937656 [27,] 0.018990381 [28,] 0.014038818 [29,] 
0.010153202 [30,] 0.058582389
```